# How to search inside an array property of an index

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, algolia

I have to retrieve a list of apps that have certain string inside of an array property:

```
const users = algoliaClient.initIndex('apps')
return users.search('myId123', { hitsPerPage: 50 });
```

The apps objects are just like this:

```
{categories: ['an', 'interesting', 'category']}
```

How can I search the index for items with a categories property that contains any item in an array of strings?

Comment: add catergories as a searchable attribute